# Open new windows and Select or Highlight the Folder

Tags: c#

How can I open a new windows explorer and select a directory ...
[image: Directory Example]

I already tried this code below:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", DirectoryPath);
//and this one, but works only to a file
Process.Start("explorer.exe /Select", DirectoryPath);
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command should be like:

```
ProcessName    Arguments
===========    =========
explorer.exe   /select, "{dir path}"
```

so the code will be:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", " /Select, " + DirectoryPath);
```

Reference: https://superuser.com/questions/512261/explorer-programmatically-select-file-directory-with-space-in-the-path

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [FolderBrowserDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) class

> Prompts the user to select a folder. This class cannot be inherited.

And also:

> Typically, after creating a new FolderBrowserDialog, you set the
>   RootFolder to the location from which to start browsing. Optionally,
>   you can set the SelectedPath to an absolute path of a subfolder of
>   RootFolder that will initially be selected.

Example:

```
FolderBrowserDialog f = new FolderBrowserDialog();
DialogResult res = f.ShowDialog();

string[] str = Directory.GetFiles(f.SelectedPath);
```

You can set the root path of your folder as well like this:

```
FolderBrowserDialog f = new FolderBrowserDialog();
f.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
f.SelectedPath = @"yourSelectedFolderPath";
f.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Your answer is totally irrelevant to what the OP has asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
String DirectoryPath = @"c:\windows\";
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/Select," + DirectoryPath);
```